# Can TortoiseSVN provide a cross-repository view of user activity?

Tags: tortoisesvn, history, commit

Is there a way I can see my commit history for a given time period across multiple repositories using TortoiseSVN? It would be nice to be able to see this, and it's a little cumbersome to get my complete commit history if I'm working in multiple repositories.

Comment: Are these multiple *unrelated* repositories?

Comment: Yes. Since the log user is saved with each commit, though, SVN *should* have the capacity to show you some kind of aggregated view. Again, it might not be possible...

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be willing to use a command-line svn client? That might lend itself to a nifty powershell script or something...

Comment: The command line client has the --xml option that should make the outputs easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to rule out the svn.exe client, you could do:

```
svn log <path_to_repo> -r1:head -q | find "william_leara" >> c:\my_commits.txt
```

Do this for every repository, and "my_commits.txt" will contain your commits from every repository.  If you don't have an obscene number of repositories, it's not a big deal.  Further example:

```
:: dump my commits
svn log http://<server>/<path1> -r1:head -q | find "william_leara" >> c:\my_commits.txt
svn log http://<server>/<path2> -r1:head -q | find "william_leara" >> c:\my_commits.txt
svn log file:///c:/src/myrepo -r1:head -q | find "william_leara" >> c:\my_commits.txt
```

. . . I think you get the idea.  Of course you can edit the range as necessary, or write a batch file that accepts arguments to specify repository/range/user, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have something like cross-repository view is using **Settings** menu and then  **Log Caching**->**Cached Repositories**. This allows to get svn repository statistics (actually, related to local usage of the particular repository) - **Details** and export repository data in the form of file set: [filename].changes.csv, [filename].merges.csv, [filename].paths.csv, **[filename].revisions.csv**, etc. The latter is the most probable you are interested in. I think it could be processed easily for example by perl to have a commit history for a given period in a form you need.